# Integral of Laplacian u over u

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \in {{R}^{n}}$ be a bounded ${{C}^{1}}$ domain (open connected set).  Assume that $u\in {{C}^{2}}\left( \Omega  \right)\cap {{C}^{1}}\left( {\bar{\Omega }} \right)$, which is not a constant function and satisfies $u>0$ on $\bar{\Omega }$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ (Neumann condition) on $\partial \Omega $.  Show that we have $\int_{\Omega }{\frac{\Delta u}{u}dx}>0$ .

I just do it by integration by part.  Is the following correct?  Please help.

$\int_{\Omega }{\frac{\Delta u}{u}dx}=\int_{\partial \Omega }{\frac{1}{u}\underbrace{\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}}_{=0}dS}+\int_{\Omega }{\frac{\nabla u}{{{u}^{2}}}dx}  =\int_{\partial \Omega }{\frac{1}{{{u}^{2}}}udS}+\int_{\Omega }{\frac{1}{2{{u}^{3}}}udx} =\int_{\partial \Omega }{\frac{1}{u}dS}+\int_{\Omega }{\frac{1}{2{{u}^{2}}}dx}\text{   }>0\\$

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\frac{\Delta u}{u}\,dx&=\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac1u \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,dS-\int_{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla (1/u)\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&=0-\int_{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla (1/u)\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\int_{\Omega}\frac{|\nabla u|^2}{u^2}\,dx \tag 3\\\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}$$

In arriving at $(1)$, we used the vector identity $\nabla \cdot \phi \vec A=\phi (\nabla \cdot \vec A)+\nabla (\phi)\cdot \vec A$ with $\vec A=\nabla u$ and $\phi =1/u$ along with the Divergence Theorem to integrate by parts.

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the Neumann Condition.

And in going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used the product rule identity $\nabla f(u)=f'(u)\nabla u$ with $f(u)=1/u$.